# Allocate hdd space and use it as RAID

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, ubuntu-server

I want to install ubuntu server in my desktop.
There are options to use a drive as RAID.
When I searched in google the uses of RAID, I realized its a different separate kind of hard disk with RAID software installed(thats what i summarized).
Now my desktop HDD is a simple 2TB WD. There is no RAID HDD in my desktop. When I am partitioning my HDD and making it RAID drive, will it work as an actual RAID HDD or will it make no difference than other partition types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now my desktop HDD is a simple 2TB WD.

RAID stands for [**R**edundant **A**rray of **I**nexpensive **D**isks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) - you cannot have a 1-disk "*array*"... while it is logically possible to achieve this using software RAID (e.g: [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux))) this is somewhere between "*completely unnecessary*", and "*a really bad idea*".

> There is no RAID HDD in my desktop

There is no significant difference between a "*RAID Hard Disk*" vs. "*Normal Hard Disk*" - in fact these terms are somewhat non-sensical. While there are hard disk models that are better suited to desktop vs. RAID environments (due to firmware tweaks, e.g: [TLER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control)) they are still inter-compatible, and can be used in the "*inappropriate*" environment.

There are however different connection types, such as [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) and [SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI) - a standard desktop likely won't have SAS.

> When I am partitioning my HDD and making it RAID drive, will it work as an actual RAID HDD or will it make no difference than other partition types?

Reading into your question, I see two likely possibilities:

1. You're using LVM and creating one partition.

   This is okay, and it allows you to extend the logical size of your volume sometime in the future by adding a second hard disk. After such an addition, you'd have something akin to [RAID 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0) (though with the data laid out [linearly rather than striped](https://sysadmincasts.com/episodes/27-lvm-linear-vs-striped-logical-volumes)) - a loss of either drive (due to failure, etc...) would likely lose all of your data, and there are no performance gains.

   Personally I'd opt against this, but it's up to you and your expected usage model.
2. You're using LVM and creating multiple partitions on one disk, added to a "*volume group*" (VG).

   This is either "*unnecessary*" or explicitly "*a really bad idea*"

   - "*Unnecessary*" - if you are creating a linear array of physical volumes (PVs) on one disk, then... there's no point, you're wasting some space to metadata, and putting arbitrary boundaries for no good reason. Just use one big one that spans all of the available space.
   - "*A really bad idea*" - if you are creating a striped array of PVs on one disk, then you will take a significant performance hit, as the hard disk will need to seek between each of the PVs over and over to perform the read/write operation.

---

See this great write-up on [LVM Linear vs Striped Logical Volumes](https://sysadmincasts.com/episodes/27-lvm-linear-vs-striped-logical-volumes) (image used below).

[image: lvm linear vs striped]

---

I'd be curious to know what you're trying to get out of using the RAID option offered...

- If you are after redundancy (i.e: one disk can fail), then you'll need two or more disks.
- If you're after performance, then you'll need two or more disks.
- If you're after future expandability, then fine - but this is less a RAID feature, and more of an LVM feature.

Comment: hmm.. ok.. ya, if my main HDD fails then the actual work of RAID will not be there, since its a part of that same HDD only.. Since my overall hardware is the same i dont think there will be any change of performance. Thank for the detailed info. I do wana go for the raid partition just for practical knowledge purpose. Thanks a lot man..